# How can I use Amazon Echo Look?

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit

How can I use Amazon Echo Look thought Alex? I found this description [https://www.amazon.com/Echo-Hands-Free-Camera-Style-Assistant/dp/B0186JAEWK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0186JAEWK) but can't find any build-in intents for communicate with Echo Look. Is this feature available already or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for the [display interface](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/display-interface-reference#display-template-reference). That should help walk you through what you need to know in order to go from developing for the Amazon Echo to the Amazon Echo Show. Essentially, what you are doing is editing the JSON response that you are sending back to Alexa.